# jquery.js:9631 POST: 404 (Not Found)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is my ajax code but when I'm calling 2nd function its throwing the error

> jquery.js:9631  error

In this scenario :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#set_value").click(function() {
    var due = document.getElementById("due_date").value;
    var freq = document.getElementById("frequency").value;

    if (due != null && freq != null && due != "" && freq != "") {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../blocks/mailer/logic.php",
        data: {
          due_days: due,
          frequency: freq,
          courseid: '.$COURSE->id.'
        }
      }).done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
        location.reload();
      });
    } else {
      alert("Due frequency and Frequency dont be null");
      document.getElementById("set_value").focus();
    }
  });

  $("#mod_value").click(function() {
    var due = document.getElementById("due_date").value;
    var freq = document.getElementById("frequency").value;

    if (due != null && freq != null && due != "" && freq != "") {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../blocks/mailer/mod/modify.php",
        data: {
          due_days: due,
          frequency: freq,
          courseid: '.$COURSE->id.'
        }
      }).done(function(data) {
        alert(data);
        location.reload();
      });
    } else {
      alert("Due frequency and Frequency dont be null");
      document.getElementById("set_value").focus();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: The least thing you should do when you post code where is to properly indent and format your code. It will not only help foreign people to read and understand your code, but it will also help you to detect problems faster.

Comment: iam using two buttons in html and calling ajax methods when button clicked on it for 1st button its working fine but when iam going for second button its throughing this error